# Y-axis incremental increase in tick marks

Tags: r

I am trying to get incremental increase with 1 ticks, currently it looks like this:

[image]

However when I try to add `axis` to get incremental increase with 1 I get:

```
axis(2, at=seq(0, 16, 1))
```

It looks like this, which doesn't look good at all:

[image]

Comment: There is not enough space for all labels. Use a smaller font or fewer labels

Comment: How can I change to smaller font? Since I need it to have increasement with 1.

Comment: run `par(cex.axis = .5)` before you make your plot, or as axis(4, cex.axis = .5)

Comment: `plot(0:15,0:15, axes=FALSE); axis(2, at=c(0,5,10,15)); axis(2, at=1:14, labels=FALSE, tck=-0.01)` Would it be okay to just have the tick marks without labels? Otherwise, you could rotate y-axis labels with `las=1` to try to make all labels visible.`cex.axis` works as well (as noted above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a couple of changes.

1. Make you font smaller: `cex.axis=0.9`
2. Rotate the numbers 90 degrees: `las=1`
3. Only plot even numbers

Which gives

```
par(cex.axis=0.9, las=1)
plot(0:16, axes=FALSE)
axis(2, seq(0, 16, 2), seq(0, 16, 2))
```

[image]